# python regex weird length issue with unicode flag

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am facing a weird regex issue. This is a simple regex to replace a-z with a space. But it only replaces up to a certain fixed length.

```
import re

s = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddd'
s = unicode(s, 'utf-8')
s = re.sub(r'[a-z]', ' ', s, re.UNICODE)
print s
```

On running this code, the output is

```
                                ccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddd
```

If I remove the `re.UNICODE` flag, then it works fine. Can someone please explain why is this happening.

Comment: I believe you need to do `flags=re.UNICODE` as that arguments position is the number of substitutions to perform... Its signature is: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`...

Comment: Yes: `re.UNICODE` is equivalent with `32`, so this just replaces the first 32 characters.

Comment: I've seen this come up a few times and answered along with how `.sub` on a compiled expression and `re.sub` also "appear" to not quite do the same thing... Can I find any of 'em though...

Comment: If you couldn't find an answer on the just marked question, please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), as you can see, the 4th positional argument is `count`. Try doing `re.sub(r'[a-z]', ' ', s, flags=re.UNICODE)`

Answer (score 1):

The fourth parameter of `re.sub` is `count`. If you want to specify `flags` you should make it a keyword parameter instead:

```
s = re.sub(r'[a-z]', ' ', s, flags=re.UNICODE)
```